# Handle date picker in iPhone 12 in Appium

Tags: appium, appium-ios, ios-ui-automation

How to automate the date picker given below in iPhone 12 using Appium?

There are no HTML tags defined for it. Coming like a popup. It's an input field.

IOS 12 date picker

[image]

Input field screenshot :

Input Date field screenshot

[image]

Comment: There are no html tags defined for it. Coming like a popup. Its an input field. Please check the screenshot.

Comment: Kindly refer above screenshots